# Adjust styles in antd 5.x

Tags: antd

I just switched from antd 4 to the latest antd 5.1.4.

A lot is different now and I am trying to get my head around. I try to change the height of the menu items. They are 40px high which I'd like to reduce.

I am trying to figure out where this styling comes from and how to adjust it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```css
.ant-menu-inline .ant-menu-item {
  height: 20px;
}
```

Output:

Default (40px)

[image: Image1]

New (20px)

[image: Image2]

I hope this helps! Thank you!!